# Toggle child TextView inside CardView based on visibility

Tags: java, android

I have the following `CardView`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="expandCollapse">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="20dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="Heading Goes Here" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_action_down" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Description Goes Here"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Now, there are many of these cardviews, so I want to make my `expandCollapse` function work with all of them.

So basically, when the `CardView` is clicked, I want it to show or hide the `Description Goes Here` `TextView` depending on it's current visibility. It will either be `GONE` or `VISIBLE`. I also want it to change the `ImageView` arrow based on the current visibility.

Basically I just want this card to expand/collapse the textview inside of it. I know how do to this, but I don't know how to select the child `TextView` dynamically inside of my function.

How exactly do I select this `TextView` when the card is clicked, considering I will not be specifying an `id` for it, since I want this to work with many different `CardView` having the exact same layout?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I simply added a tag to the TextView with `android:tag="desc"`

Then I used `TextView textView = view.findViewWithTag("desc");` in my onClick function.